# How do I capture the inbox items of microsoft outlook

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automation, qtp, testcomplete

I need to capture the inbox items of microsoft outlook to automate it.  I tried with TestComplete,QTP and VSTS . But did not able to capture the object for it. Is there any aother tool to do it. As VSTS is a microsoft product does it can able to capture inbox items?Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can find a sample script demonstrating how to work Microsoft Outlook from TestComplete in this How To article: [Receive e-mail messages via MS Outlook](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/9022/).